# Recently Viewed Products Not Showing (on live server only)

Tags: reports

For all user types.

It works perfectly on my development WAMP environment, but does not work on live server.

local.xml

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" after="-" name="bottom.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
```

When viewing the product page with template hints, the block exists at the bottom of the page, but with no content.

When I put a random html string into the product_viewed.phtml file, above everything, even this does not output - the phtml file is not even being called on the live server.

I would assume `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed` is returning a blank collection - but I cannot find out why, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the template wouldn't be loaded if the collection is empty; which seems to be your case. Go to the admin and go to `Reports > Products > Most Viewed`, check there is actual data there.

If not, go to `Reports > Refresh Statistics`, pick 'Most Viewed' and refresh Lifetime statistics. They should be refreshed automatically though, so make sure your cron is set up and properly running.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. It seems the report was empty, (but both on my dev machine and live server). Now refreshed but I still have the same problem - anything else I can try?

Comment: Cancel that. Interestingly enough, I tried the site in an incognito window and it's working :). Not sure what the fix was, possibly the refresh or some issue with my browser. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Going to mark this as the answer as it may be a possible fix for some.