# Mostly viewed products are not in report_viewed_product_index table in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3.4, mostview-product-collection

> I want to show the most viewed products but when I look at the backend 
>   Report->Viewed is empty. Also, I looked at the report_viewed_product_index this table is empty

**how I can get mostly viewed products?**

Answer (score 4):

To check this you can go to:

> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Reports

Check if the reports are enabled.

[image: Magento 2 Reports enabled]

Answer (score 0):

First, try to Refresh Statistics. You will find it at reports -> Statistics -> Refresh Statistics. After that check, it will work fine.

Comment: Still now empty....

i refreshed ...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/69874/73525 tried this answer also...